# SQLite: How can I add data from from different rows when summing up other ones?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a card game analyzation program that stores the results in an SQLite database with integer columns for the following values: round, table, game, pair, and score.

The schema of the "score" table is:

```
CREATE TABLE score(
    round INTEGER,
    table_number INTEGER,
    game INTEGER,
    pair_or_player INTEGER,
    score INTEGER
);
```

E. g. a simple case for only two pairs and one round with two games each, where 21 points can be reached looks like this:

```
+-------+--------------+------+----------------+-------+
| round | table_number | game | pair_or_player | score |
+-------+--------------+------+----------------+-------+
| 1     | 1            | 1    | 1              | 8     |
| 1     | 1            | 1    | 2              | 21    |
| 1     | 1            | 2    | 1              | 21    |
| 1     | 1            | 2    | 2              | 14    |
+-------+--------------+------+----------------+-------+
```

A simple `SELECT round, table_number, game, pair_or_player, score FROM score` outputs:

```
1|1|1|1|8
1|1|1|2|21
1|1|2|1|21
1|1|2|2|14
```

What I need is an additional column with 21 minus the score of the opponent of the same game (identified by the same round, table_number and game, and a different pair_or_player), the result of the respective query would be:

```
1|1|1|1|8 |0
1|1|1|2|21|13
1|1|2|1|21|7
1|1|2|2|14|0
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you list all your column names?

Comment: Like in the post: round, table, game, pair, score.

Answer (score 2):

You need to inner join the table with itself.

(I'm not entirely sure what you mean by pair, but let's assume there's an ID which identifies each match, a match being composed of two records, one for the winner, one for the loser):

```
SELECT winners.pair, winners.score, losers.pair, losers.score
FROM (SELECT pair, score FROM score WHERE score = 21) as winners
INNER JOIN (SELECT pair, score FROM score WHERE score < 21) as losers
ON winners.match_id = losers.match_id;
```

Comment: "pair" is one of the column names, see above. And you're right with your assumption. I'll check your code asap …

Comment: The query didn't produce what I need … I edited the original post, so that it hopefully will be more clear what I need. Perhaps, you want to hae a look at it again?

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself.

```
SELECT
    a.round,
    a.table_number,
    a.game,
    a.pair_or_player,
    a.score,
    21 - b.score
FROM
    score AS a,
    score AS b
WHERE
    a.round = b.round
    AND a.table_number = b.table_number
    AND a.game = b.game
    AND a.pair_or_player != b.pair_or_player
```

does the trick :-)

Comment: Good job! Now to finalise, Replace the WHERE with an INNER JOIN and ON clause. It will give the same result, but "Where" is really for filtering, whereas INNER JOIN/ON is for joining. It will come in handy when you add filters.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do so ;-)